# squid https proxy not working after chrome browser update

Tags: https, proxy, squid

squid  work normally as https proxy for almost 2 years ,but after chrome updateing to version (94.0.4606.61),it does'nt work any more .

The error log in  access.log was "NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers"  and the error in cache.log was "kid1| Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 22: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1) (1/-1)".
And here is my config .

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535 # unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl HEAD method HEAD


http_access deny !Safe_ports
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
#http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
#http_access allow localhost
http_port 54332

https_port 843 cert=cert.pem  key=privkey.pem


auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 24 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
#centos
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
#ubuntu
#auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl auth_user proxy_auth REQUIRED
# http_access deny all
http_access allow auth_user
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3


# based on http://code.google.com/p/ghebhes/downloads/detail?name=tunning.conf&can=2&q=


#All File
# refresh_pattern -i \.(3gp|7z|ace|asx|avi|bin|cab|dat|deb|rpm|divx|dvr-ms) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(rar|jar|gz|tgz|tar|bz2|iso|m1v|m2(v|p)|mo(d|v)|(x-|)flv) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(jp(e?g|e|2)|gif|pn[pg]|bm?|tiff?|ico|swf|css|js) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(mp(e?g|a|e|1|2|3|4)|mk(a|v)|ms(i|u|p)) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(og(x|v|a|g)|rar|rm|r(a|p)m|snd|vob|wav) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(pp(s|t)|wax|wm(a|v)|wmx|wpl|zip|cb(r|z|t)) 1440 100% 129600 reload-into-ims


# refresh_pattern -i \.(doc|pdf)$ 1440 50% 43200 reload-into-ims
# refresh_pattern -i \.(html|htm)$ 1440 50% 40320 reload-into-ims


# refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
# refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
# refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
# refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$ 0 20% 2880
# refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320


# http options
via off


# memory cache options
cache_mem 512 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 256 KB


# disk cache
#cache_dir diskd /var/spool/squid3 10240 16 256
#maximum_object_size 20480 KB


# timeouts
# forward_timeout 10 seconds
# connect_timeout 10 seconds
# read_timeout 10 seconds
# write_timeout 10 seconds
# client_lifetime 59 minutes
# request_timeout 30 seconds
half_closed_clients off


#
forwarded_for delete
dns_v4_first on
ipcache_size 4096
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8,  1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems to the cert issue ,which chrome consider it was expire . But it works fine in my nginx . The problem should be ERR_PROXY_CERTIFICATE_INVALID ,chrome prompts